# Very weird behavior with glViewport

Tags: c++, opengl, viewport

I got the render loop working fine, but now that I added more objects to be rendered there seems to be some strange behavior happening when switching between viewports

Case 1 : single viewport active that is full screen, everything works fine

Case 2 : two viewports, one on left side one on right side, gizmos render correct, however world renders in the wrong viewport, the two are swapped. When moving the camera in one viewport, the camera for the other viewport moves instead (just for world rendering mind you, gizmos render correct)

My code looks like this.

```
Viewport* viewport;
for (int vi = 0; vi < viewports->size(); vi++)
{
    viewport = (*viewports)[vi];

    if (viewport->flags & ViewportFlags::Active)
    {
        // Set Viewport //
        GLint pixPosX = (GLint)viewport->pixelPosition.x;
        GLint pixPosY = (GLint)viewport->pixelPosition.y;
        GLsizei pixSizX = (GLsizei)viewport->pixelSize.x;
        GLsizei pixSizY = (GLsizei)viewport->pixelSize.y;
        glViewport(pixPosX, pixPosY, pixSizX, pixSizY);

        // Render World //
        if (world != nullptr)
        {
            world->Render(viewport);
        }

        // Render Gizmos //
        if (viewport->flags & ViewportFlags::RenderGizmos)
        {
            gizmo->Render(viewport);
        }

        // Render Viewport Frame //
        if (viewport->flags & ViewportFlags::DrawFrame)
        {
            gizmo->OverrideShaderColor(glm::vec4(1, 0, 0, 1));
            if (viewport->flags & ViewportFlags::Focused)
                gizmo->RenderFrame(viewport, glm::vec4(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1));
            else
                gizmo->RenderFrame(viewport, glm::vec4(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1));
        }
    }
}


// Reset glViewport for UI //
glViewport(0, 0, window->wData->width, window->wData->width);
...
```

As a hack I moved the `glViewport()` between the `world->Render()` and `gizmos->Render()` and commented the `glViewport` reset line at the end of the loop, and this fixed it. But it's still not correct, and I need to reset viewport at the end for rendering UI.

It seems like somehow in the for loop going through each viewport, the glViewport line executes after world for some reason, as if it lagged behind.

With the hack, it looks something like this:

```
Viewport* viewport;
for (int vi = 0; vi < viewports->size(); vi++)
{
    viewport = (*viewports)[vi];

    if (viewport->flags & ViewportFlags::Active)
    {
        // Set Viewport //
        GLint pixPosX = (GLint)viewport->pixelPosition.x;
        GLint pixPosY = (GLint)viewport->pixelPosition.y;
        GLsizei pixSizX = (GLsizei)viewport->pixelSize.x;
        GLsizei pixSizY = (GLsizei)viewport->pixelSize.y;

        // Render World //
        if (world != nullptr)
        {
            world->Render(viewport);
        }
        
        glViewport(pixPosX, pixPosY, pixSizX, pixSizY);

        // Render Gizmos //
        if (viewport->flags & ViewportFlags::RenderGizmos)
        {
            gizmo->Render(viewport);
        }

        // Render Viewport Frame //
        if (viewport->flags & ViewportFlags::DrawFrame)
        {
            gizmo->OverrideShaderColor(glm::vec4(1, 0, 0, 1));
            if (viewport->flags & ViewportFlags::Focused)
                gizmo->RenderFrame(viewport, glm::vec4(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1));
            else
                gizmo->RenderFrame(viewport, glm::vec4(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1));
        }
    }
}


// Reset glViewport for UI //
// glViewport(0, 0, window->wData->width, window->wData->width);
...
```

Edit : [Adding a video to show the problem](https://streamable.com/jrnlfm)

Comment: Is there any other call to `glViewport` except for the ones shown here? For example, in the world->Render method?

Comment: Nope, all the calls are accounted for

Comment: So `viewports` is a pointer to an array of `Viewport*`s (i.e. either `Viewport* (*viewports)[size]` or `Viewport*** viewports`)? That looks like one level of indirection too many to me.

Comment: std::vector<Viewport*>* viewports;
However I checked in the loop, it iterates over them correctly.

Comment: "Nope, all the calls are accounted for" - I'd have another look. Especially if there are 3rd party libs involved. Got burned by Qt not long ago setting viewport at weird times.